# Javascript: Handling notifications webview

Tags: javascript, webview, notifications

Hello I have a Cocoa application with some webview. I wish to get the browser notifications to display them in local notification. Currently there is no native support for the Apple WebKit to display web notifications from the WKWebview.

So Im looking for javascript solution, in my webviews I would like to inject javascript code that listen on the notifications of the web page, and as soon as the notification is handled make a console.log of the body of the notification.

There is a way in javascript to put a listener / observer on a page to detect web notification?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change your notification system completely to JS. You could use a library like [Notify.js](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com)